# PDF/html/epub downloads doesn't update for either latest or (manually triggered) stable build

Tags: read-the-docs

In my project, http://lacinia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, the downloads (PDF, epub, single-page HTML) doesn't update on a build.  It looks like it builds, but the download link keeps downloading a version from Oct 03.  I've done some significant work since then.

The latest link works correctly, showing changes within minutes of my pushing changes.

It's not clear to me whether the build works, but the latest files are simply not put in the correct folder for download, or if the build is broken in some way.

I'd appreciate any clues on how to fix or at least properly diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around, I found the "[wipe build](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html#deleting-a-stale-or-broken-build-environment)" functionality; that plus, perhaps, a Cmd-Shift-R, to ensure I was downloading fresh and not from local cache, got me the latest versions.